# Ember RESTAdapter - hasMany relationship in model - how to send empty array with POST?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Ember noob here -

I have two models with a **hasMany** relationship like below -

```
var Season = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    periods: DS.hasMany('period', {
        async: false
    })
});

var Period = DS.Model.extend({
    from: DS.attr('date'),
    to: DS.attr('date'),
    season: DS.belongsTo('season')
});
```

A Season can exist without any Periods -
This is how I create a Season record and save --

```
        var season = this.store.createRecord('season', {
            name: name
        });

        season.save().then(function(season){
                   /* season saved */
        });
```

The POST request payload looks like this --

```
   {
    "season" : {
         "name" : "test"
     }
   }
```

But the backend API expects the payload to be like this -- with an empty periods array

```
    {
    "season" : {
         "name" : "test"
         "periods" : []
     }
   }
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change what ember is sending to your server by modifying the serializer, you can either override `SeasonSerializer` for just that model or `ApplicationSerializer` to do it app wide.

see this section of the API docs http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_serialize

Something like:

```
App.SeasonSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serialize: function(snapshot, options) {
    var json = this._super(snapshot, options);

    if(json.periods === undefined) {
      json.periods = [];
    }

    return json;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks -- that is what I ended up doing!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify the server, this should do the trick:

```
App.SeasonSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serialize: function(snapshot, options) {
    var json = this._super(snapshot, options);

    if (Ember.isEmpty(json.periods)) {
      json.periods = [];
    }

    return json;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, you can make a serializer that will send [ ]'s for all hasMany relationships that are empty.

serializers/application.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serialize(snapshot, options) {
    var json = {};

    snapshot.eachAttribute(function(name) {
      json[name] = snapshot.attr(name);
    });

    snapshot.eachRelationship(function(name, relationship) {
      if (relationship.kind === 'hasMany') {
        const list = snapshot.hasMany(name, { ids: true });
        if(Ember.isEmpty(list)){
          json[name] = [];
        }else{
          json[name] = list;
        }
      }
    });

    return json;
  }
});
```